# Invalid ELF header when loading library from Python using ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, python, g++, ctypes

I am just getting started with gcc on Linux.  I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_79.html), except that I am using the g++ compiler.

hello_fn.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void 
hello (const char * name)
{
  printf ("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

bye_fn.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void 
bye (void)
{
  printf ("Goodbye!\n");
}
```

hello.h

```
void hello (const char * name);
void bye (void);
```

I then run the following in the shell:

```
$ g++ -Wall -c hello_fn.cpp
$ g++ -Wall -c bye_fn.cpp
$ ar cr libhello.a hello_fn.o bye_fn.o
```

Then I try the following from python:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes 
>>> test = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'/home/oob/development/libtest/libhello.a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/jeff/development/libtest/libhello.a: invalid ELF header
```

My idea was to write some functions in c++ and call them from Python.  Any ideas?

UPDATE: I was able to get things "working".  Based on what Cat Plus Plus said, I may not go this direction for new code, but I was able to get this to work with a large legacy c++ library that I was porting from Windows to Linux.  We need a frontend to call some long running functions from this library, so I thought Python might be easiest.  The functions create a lot of output and only return an integer return code, so maybe I can avoid the "painful" stuff Cat Plus Plus was saying.

Here is what I did.

Modified hello_fn.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

extern "C" int 
hello (void)
{
  return 16;
}
```

Modified by_fn.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

extern "C" void 
bye (void)
{
  printf ("Goodbye!\n");
}
```

Modified hello.h

```
extern "C" int hello (void);
extern "C" void bye (void);
```

buildscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

rm *.o
rm *.so

g++ -fpic -g -c -Wall hello_fn.cpp
g++ -fpic -g -c -Wall bye_fn.cpp
#make a shared library, not a static library (thanks cat plus plus)
g++ -shared -o libhello.so hello_fn.o bye_fn.o
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ctypes

c = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'/home/jeff/development/libtest/libhello.so')
a = c.hello()
print 'hello was ' + str(a)
c.bye()
```

Try it in the terminal....

```
oob@ubuntu:~/development/libtest$ ./build_script.sh 
oob@ubuntu:~/development/libtest$ python test.py 
hello was 16
Goodbye!
```

Our legacy library doesn't really use any windows-specific c++ stuff (thanks to the guy who wrote that code), so it has been a pretty easy port.  We had several functions that used extern "C" to expose functions.  For the port, I have made the following changes:

```
#ifdef LINUX
#define __stdcall
#endif
#ifdef WINDOWS
#define __stdcall __stdcall
#endif
```

And for one of our functions, I can just leave it unchanged, for example:

```
extern "C" long __stdcall reform_proj {
    //do a bunch of stuff
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ctypes` is for loading shared libraries. `ar` creates archives of object files, also known as *static* libraries. You can't load that file with `ctypes`, it will only be understood by the linker.

Another issue is that using C++ shared libraries via `ctypes` is painful if not downright impossible. Just don't. Use [Cython](http://cython.org/) instead, and write a proper Python extension that interfaces with your C++ code (then you can link it either statically or dynamically, and it'll work).

Another option is [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/), but it's somewhat less documented, but has a benefit of defining Python module directly in your C++ code, instead of using wrappers written in another language.

Third is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), but I've never used it, so can't tell you how well it works in practice.

Comment: Thanks.  Static vs shared is what I needed to get started.  See my update for how I got things working for this small example.  I will definitely take your advice (about cython) for any code I plan on writing in the future.